# AngularJS pass variable from custom directive to template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I made a custom directive:

js part:

```
angular.module("myDirectives", []).directive("ngShowbox", function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      title: "="
    },
    template: "<a href='#' ng-click='show($event)'>{{title}}</a>",
    controller: function($scope, $element){
      $scope.show = function(event){
        // do something...
      }      
    }
  }
});
```

html part:

```
<ng-showbox title="whatToPutHere??"></ng-showbox>
```

I would like to pass some text from the title attribute,
then my template will show the text.
How can I make it?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use @ in directive scope:-

```
scope: {
      title: "@"
    },
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dSV7cN7cg8iZScSkV81x?p=preview) for you :)

Comment: just a note, if you assign the value of title to a controller scope value, then you need to use `title: "="`. :), if you need just the string value, not as a scope value inside the `title`  you can use ``title: "@"``

Comment: Yup exactly :) "=" will give you two way binding power where as "@" just bind the string to the scope.